# label_form_instance in form not returning html to template using mark_safe

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-templates

i have this form:

```
class BookingForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    vehicle_category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None)
    
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.fields['vehicle_category'].label_from_instance = self.label_from_instance
        ...
    
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return mark_safe(f'<img src="{obj.icon.url}" height="20" width="20"> <strong>{obj.name}</strong>')
```

in template:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Vehicle Category*</label>
       <div class="input">
           {{ form.vehicle_category }}
           {{ form.vehicle_category.errors }}
       </div>
</div>
```

but the form only return the vehicle_category.name. if i take out the `mark_safe` it return the correct string of what should be an html. but when i add `mark_safe` it seems to remove the html, even the `<strong>` tag dont have effect on `{obj.name}`. What is wrong with that?
Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You've to pass **QuerySet** in `ModelChoiceField`

Comment: yes, sorry for the incomplete code but i did pass the queryset in `__init__` method

Answer (score 0):

My bad, i didnt know that an `<option>` tag cant contain anymore html element. So i think its impossible to achieve what i want

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).